# two php classes with same name and same namespace how to use/import one of them

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to php, and having an issue in using classes with same namespaces.

I have two traits:

Trait 1:

Namespace: `Laravel\Cashier\Billable`

Directory: `laravel\cashier\src\Billable.php`

Trait 2:

Namespace: `Laravel\Cashier\Billable`

Directory: `laravel\cashier-braintree\src\Billable.php`

**How can i use the traits in my code without mixing them up ?!**

Comment: Include the file with the class you want to use only

Answer (score -1):

I suggest renaming one of the classes or change the namespace to one of them. Namespaces are used in order to avoid collision.